# PHP shell_exec stops working at second Ajax call

Tags: php, ajax, shell-exec

So I am making a simple website for personal use, it sends an Post request via Ajax, PHP code is something like that:

```
    $cmd = "some command";
    $r = shell_exec($cmd);

    echo $r;
```

Now, the first time I send the request it works, but if I send more requests without refreshing whole page it returns nothing. PHP script does execute, just shell_exec returns nothing. I have no idea what is causing this. 
(Debian, Apache2, PHP7.0)

ajax code:

```
$.post("exec.php", {command: val}).done(function(data){      
     self.outp.append(data);
});
```

And I confirmed that val is correct, if in PHP i add something to $r (example: $r .= "test") it does return that.

@Edit I've found out using GET insted of POST makes the problem disappear, it does not really resolve the problem, but it's something.

Comment: What you do you get in network tab in your dev tools

Comment: Status: 200, type: xhr, initiator: jquery-3.3.1.min.js:2 on every request

Comment: There is my very simple open source project that does what you exactly need [PHP-Shell-Terminal](https://github.com/g3ck/PHP-Shell-Terminal)

Comment: @G3ck that's cool but I want to know what is causing this and what am I doing wrong if that's the case

Comment: I need to see some more code that you use

Comment: Can you show the code of how you call ajax

Comment: The code from your question is correct

Comment: Added ajax code to orginal post

Comment: I think the problem its `self`. Unless set elsewhere, the value of `self` is `window`. This means that you change all content of `window`which can be not correct after `append`

Comment: try to create ex. `<div id="#output"></div>` on the end of document. After change `self.outp.append(data);` to `$( "#output" ).append( "<p>" + data + "</p>");`

Comment: self is defined inside class like this: let self = this; As I said before, I'm getting response from the server, I can display it just the part that should be returned by shell_exec is blank. If I do <?php return shell_exec(command)."test"; ?> then in Ajax I'm getting just the "test" part.

Comment: ok, than in your case `self` = `this`...Inside the callback, this refers to the jqXHR object of the Ajax call, not the element the event handler was bound to

Comment: No, it's defined before in the class method, in this case self is reffering to the object it's called from, it has to be as on the first try it does work, I do get response from server and it does get appended to self.outp, but only the first time, as I mentioned before it stops working at second call.